# Extract parameters from EMCluster package

Tags: r, cluster-computing, gaussian, expectation-maximization

is there a way to extract parameters of the Gaussian distributions (mean and variance) using R's EMCluster package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access memebers of `emret` object by `Mu` - for means and `LTSigma` for dispersions as follows:

```
library(EMCluster)
set.seed(123)
x1 <- da1$da
class(emobj)
emobj <- simple.init(x1, nclass = 3)
emobj$Mu
#        [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] 184.6037124  170.59132
# [2,] 117.2505083 -134.48005
# [3,]  -0.7252975  -18.01958

emobj$LTSigma
#        [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] 24649.929 21479.2133 28175.9235
# [2,]  4971.433  1079.4590   569.7259
# [3,]  2263.597  -413.6173  8381.9084
```